# How to make text normal and not italic in frame?

Tags: mdframed, ntheorem

How can you make the text normal in the frame below and not italic?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\definecolor{superlightred}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain} 
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred, ntheorem]{example}{}[]


\begin{document}

\begin{example}[2014.1]
This is an example and here is a lot of text.  \\ \\
\textbf{a)} Find the relationship between the components. 
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `\theorembodyfont{\upshape]` right after `\theoremstyle`. This being said, I think it is better to use the `empty` theorem style. I also improved a bit the code, using an `enumerate` environment with the suitable parameters using `enumitem`, so that you only have to type `\item` to obtain the correct counter, automatically formatted.

You even have the possibility, with enumitem, to create your own dedicated list, say `examples` with these parameters set  in the preamble, with the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\definecolor{superlightred}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\theoremstyle{empty}%
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred, ntheorem]{example}{}
\newlist{examples}{enumerate}{1}% <- max depth
\setlist[examples]{label=\alph*), font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[2014.1]
This is an example and here is a lot of text.
\begin{examples}
\item
Find the relationship between the components.
\end{examples}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to call `[label=\alph*), font=\bfseries, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, topsep=4pt]` once somwhere and it remember it every time I have `\being{enumerate}\end{enumerate}`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I've updated my my code. F.y.i., it is explained in the documentation of enumitem, § 7 Cloning the basic lists, pp.17-18.

Comment: Thank you once more!

Comment: You're welcome! It's a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in `ntheorem`'s [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem), the font of the theorem body can be changed using the `\theorembodyfont` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{superlightred}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=superlightred, ntheorem]{example}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[2014.1]
This is an example and here is a lot of text.  \\ \\
\textbf{a)} Find the relationship between the components. 
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\theoremstyle{definition}` before the `\newmdtheoremenv` command. (However, it gave a slight error: Unknown theoremstyle `definition'. I used it together with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` without error.)